# Portable way in C++ to get desktop resolution

Tags: c++, gcc, portability, screen-resolution

I'm making a C++ game, and I want it to automatically get the user's desktop resolution.

I've found windows-only solutions so far - is there a way/library to find the resolution on Windows/Mac/Linux?

Comment: Apparently Qt has `QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();`. That wasn't pulled from docs, and I've never used Qt, so sorry if it's wrong.

Comment: I don't think something completely portable exists...

Comment: Portable code for graphics? No way. (@Mystical +1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several libraries helping you at getting the low-level stuff to work out. You'll probably need more stuff on those platforms anyways, so I'll list some:

- [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) is a **C++ library** abstracting much of the I/O stuff, including display management. Also supports several platforms.
- The classic [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), although being a **C library** is widely used in platform independent game development and supports several platforms. Like SFML, it does more than just display management.
- [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/index.html), see [wardds answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13421669/1248008), also a **C library** and also poses an abstraction layer, but more focused on display and keyboard/mouse I/O instead of broader I/O (audio etc.)

Comment: Oh, I'm using SFML already. I didn't know it had such a function, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: [This blog post, section Getting the Current Display Mode](https://sfmlcoder.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/video-modes-and-windowing/) gives code how to do.

Answer (score 6):

[GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/index.html) provides a crossplatform (for Windows, Mac, and Linux) way to get the desktop video mode. It is a **C api**, but it **will work in C++.** The relevant function (and documentation) is here:

`void glfwGetDesktopMode( GLFWvidmode *mode )`

**Parameters**

`mode`
Pointer to a `GLFWvidmode` structure, which will be filled out by the function.

**Return values**

The `GLFWvidmode` structure pointed to by mode is filled out with the desktop video mode.

**Description**

This function returns the desktop video mode in a `GLFWvidmode` structure. See `glfwGetVideoModes`
for a definition of the `GLFWvidmode` structure.

**Notes**

The color depth of the desktop display is always reported as the number of bits for each individual color
component (red, green and blue), even if the desktop is not using an RGB or RGBA color format. For
instance, an indexed 256 color display may report RedBits = 3, GreenBits = 3 and BlueBits = 2, which
adds up to 8 bits in total.

The desktop video mode is the video mode used by the desktop at the time the GLFW window was
opened, not the current video mode (which may differ from the desktop video mode if the GLFW
window is a fullscreen window).

```
typedef struct {
  int Width, Height; // Video resolution
  int RedBits; // Number of red bits
  int GreenBits; // Number of green bits
  int BlueBits; // Number of blue bits
} GLFWvidmode;
```

See [Jonas Wielicki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13421705/1431696) for alternatives.

Answer (score 6):

I did a cross-platform c++ function:

```
#if WIN32
  #include <windows.h>
#else
  #include <X11/Xlib.h>
#endif

//...

void getScreenResolution(int &width, int &height) {
#if WIN32
    width  = (int) GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    height = (int) GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
#else
    Display* disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Screen*  scrn = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(disp);
    width  = scrn->width;
    height = scrn->height;
#endif
}

int main() {
    int width, height;
    getScreenResolution(width, height);
    printf("Screen resolution: %dx%d\n", width, height);
}
```