# How to get the display's dimensions on whichever screen a C++ program is running on (without needing to download libraries)?

Tags: c++, terminal, c++17, screen

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421399/portable-way-in-c-to-get-desktop-resolution/13421705#13421705), with external libraries, but I just want to know, is there any way I can get a monitor's dimensions using default libraries in C/C++?

Also, I came to know that the headers `"Wtypes.h"` and `"MacTypes.h"` can help, but it is not clear how to use them. Can someone please guide me through this?

Comment: This cannot be done using Standard C++ only. You will need to use your OS's libraries to obtain the information.

Comment: How to do that in MacOS?

Comment: Which screen do you want the dimensions of (for systems with > 1 monitor)?

Comment: @MarshallClow for systems with MacOS with 1 monitor only.